# Problemas con phpMailer al enviar archivos adjuntos

Tags: php, phpmailer

tengo problemas con los archivos adjuntos en phpMailer. Si cargo un archivo que no pesa como un .txt si lo carga pero al momento de querer enviar un .xls, se envía el correo pero el archivo adjunto no. Qué podría estar pasando? No creo que se error en el código ya que el archivo .txt si se envía.

Agradecería cualquier comentario muchas gracias.

```
if (isset($_POST['registrando'])) {
        include "class.phpmailer.php";
        include "class.smtp.php";
      $email_user = "silvermask26@gmail.com";
      $email_password = "Nobleteam22";
      $the_subject = "Registro de Indicadores";
      $address_to = "silvermask26@gmail.com";
      $from_name = utf8_encode("Informacion Estrategica");
      $archivo = $_POST['file'];
      $phpmailer = new PHPMailer();

 // ---------- datos de la cuenta de Gmail --------------------
$phpmailer->Username = $email_user;
$phpmailer->Password = $email_password; 
 //-------------------------------------------------------------
// $phpmailer->SMTPDebug = 1;
   $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
   $phpmailer->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // GMail
   $phpmailer->Port = 465;
   $phpmailer->IsSMTP(); // use SMTP
   $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true;

   $phpmailer->setFrom($phpmailer->Username,$from_name);
   $phpmailer->AddAddress($address_to); // recipients email

   $phpmailer->Subject = $the_subject;  
   $phpmailer->Body .= "<p>'Se envia la matriz para verificar la información'</p>";
   $phpmailer->IsHTML(true);
   $phpmailer->AddAttachment($archivo);

     $phpmailer->Send();
}
```

```
<form method="POST" action="onco.php">  
 <input type="file" required name="file" id="file" class="inputfile" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple/>
 <input type="text" required id="indicador" onkeypress="return justNumbers(event);" class="onco" name="TxQuimio" autocomplete="off"><br>
 <input type="text" required id="indicador" onkeypress="return justNumbers(event);" class="onco" name="TxRDT" autocomplete="off"><br>
 <input type="submit" value="Registrar" class="btnonco" name="registrando">
```

Comment: ¿Qué código estás usando? ¿Estás implementando un control de errores para saber lo que está ocurriendo?

Comment: Edite la pregunta añadiendo el código que estoy usando, no tengo la parte del control de errores

Comment: No creo que puedas poner tu archivo con solamente esto: `$archivo = $_POST['file'];` ¿podrías mostrar el formulario desde el cual estás tomando el archivo?

Comment: Olvide pegar el cierre del <form> pero ese es el código del formulario

Comment: Lo primero es que tu formulario debe ser declarado como multipart, ya que transmitirá archivos adjuntos, por tanto, debes declararlo así: `<form method="POST" action="onco.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">`, luego,  en PHP añade el archivo así: `if (isset($_FILES['file']) &&
    $_FILES['file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $phpmailer->AddAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],
                         $_FILES['file']['name']);
}` preguntando por el estado del POST y usando `tmp_name` y `name` de la super global `$_FILES`.

Comment: Ok amigo, intento agregando lo que me comentas, pero por que funciona con archivos pequeños aun sin tener lo que me comentas del multipart

Comment: No sabría decirte, habría que hacer pruebas e investigar. Lo cierto es que, hasta donde sé, hay que usar `multipart` cuando se adjuntan archivos en los formularios.

Comment: Gracias amigo, con los cambios que mencionaste ya se envía el archivo .xls que necesito

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[W3C Recommendation indica](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) que cuando se envíen archivos adjuntos en los formularios se use el `enctype multipart/form-data`:

> The content type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" is inefficient
>   for sending large quantities of binary data or text containing
>   non-ASCII characters. The content type "multipart/form-data" should be
>   used for submitting forms that contain files, non-ASCII data, and
>   binary data.
>
> The content "multipart/form-data" follows the rules of all multipart
>   MIME data streams as outlined in [RFC2045]. The definition of
>   "multipart/form-data" is available at the [IANA] registry.
>
> A "multipart/form-data" message contains a series of parts, each
>   representing a successful control. The parts are sent to the
>   processing agent in the same order the corresponding controls appear
>   in the document stream. Part boundaries should not occur in any of the
>   data; how this is done lies outside the scope of this specification.
>
> As with all multipart MIME types, each part has an optional
>   "Content-Type" header that defaults to "text/plain". User agents
>   should supply the "Content-Type" header, accompanied by a "charset"
>   parameter.
>
> ---
>
> El tipo de contenido "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" es ineficaz
>   para enviar grandes cantidades de datos binarios o texto que contiene
>   caracteres no ASCII. El tipo de contenido "multipart/form-data" se
>   debe usar para enviar formularios que contengan archivos, datos que no
>   sean ASCII y datos binarios.
>
> El contenido "multipart/form-data" sigue las reglas de todos los
>   flujos de datos MIME multiparte como se describe en [RFC2045]. La
>   definición de "multipart/form-data" está disponible en el registro
>   [IANA].
>
> Un mensaje de "multipart/form-data" contiene una serie de partes, cada
>   una representando un control exitoso. Las partes se envían al agente
>   de procesamiento en el mismo orden en que aparecen los controles
>   correspondientes en la secuencia del documento. Los límites de las
>   partes no deben aparecer en ninguno de los datos; cómo se hace esto
>   queda fuera del alcance de esta especificación.
>
> Al igual que con todos los tipos MIME de varias partes, cada parte
>   tiene un encabezado opcional "Tipo de contenido" que por defecto es
>   "texto/plano". Los agentes de usuario deben proporcionar el encabezado
>   "Tipo de contenido", acompañado de un parámetro "conjunto de
>   caracteres".

Cuando no especificas el `enctype` en un formulario, éste toma aquel que tienen los formularios por defecto que `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Y como dice lo indicado más arriba, no es suficiente para enviar archivos grandes.

Por tanto, debes indicar en tu formulario un `enctype` adecuadado para poder enviar archivos grandes:

```
<form method="POST" action="onco.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Luego, la obtención del archivo que se está enviando también cambia. El archivo no se encuentra en la super global `_$POST`, sino en la super globar `$_FILES`, es como decir que hay varias partes en el `form`, en la parte POST están los datos normales, los de los `input` de texto y demás, y en la parte FILES están los archivos que se adjuntaron.

Podrás conseguir tu archivo así para agregarlo al email:

```
if (isset($_FILES['file']) && $_FILES['file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) { 
    $phpmailer->AddAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['name']); 
}
```

*That's all folks!*